# How can I create a fine colour scale in R, for plotting node colour with igraph?

Tags: r, colors, igraph

I am using igraph to plot a small network (21 nodes) on R. I would like the nodes to be coloured according to the vector postMean, which has the values:

```
[1] -0.035275268  0.016065216 -0.009860104 -0.110333756  0.027173563

[6]  0.003732149 -0.015728577 -0.015447753 -0.015458429 -0.031747722

[11]  0.050184673  0.052410534  0.025986002  0.059460753  0.044158671

[16] -0.302219356  0.065311113  0.012006393  0.019186883 -0.006812400

[21]  0.196030557
```

How can I adjust the scale of the colours so that it will indicate values of the postMean vector, when the numbers are small? I would like a really fine gray-scale, but all I seem to be able to get at the moment are some nodes white and some nodes black.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some self-contained code? In general, tot ge a grey scale you can use `grey()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rescale()` function from the plotrix package to rescale your vector from 0 to 1, then use the `gray()` function to convert these to gray scale colors.

```
library(igraph)
library(plotrix)
vcol <- gray(rescale(postMean, c(0, 1)))
tkplot(graph, vertex.color=vcol)
```

If you don't want the range of colors to extend all the way to black and white, you can reduce the range of values that you rescale to, for example:

```
vcol <- gray(rescale(postMean, c(0.1, 0.9)))
```